# Error for view admob ads

Tags: android, google-analytics, admob

I have the follow error when I try to view de insterstitial ads from admon

> ```
> > 12-29 13:04:08.331 12015-12015/org.lili14.imagenesparawhatsapp
> > I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es 12-29
> > 13:04:08.681 12015-12015/org.lili14.imagenesparawhatsapp I/Ads:
> > Starting ad request. 12-29 13:04:08.701
> > 12015-12015/org.lili14.imagenesparawhatsapp I/Choreographer: Skipped
> > 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main
> > thread. 12-29 13:04:19.081 12015-12034/org.lili14.imagenesparawhatsapp
> > W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0 12-29
> > 13:04:19.081 12015-12015/org.lili14.imagenesparawhatsapp W/Ads: Failed
> > to load ad: 0
> ```

I added the google play service this is the code for the ads

```
public void showFullScreenAd() {
    try {


        interstitial
                .setAdUnitId(ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID);

        // Check the logcat output for your hashed device ID to get test ads
        // on
        // a physical device.
        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice("98C0D5CB2DE5053D838806F85C1F9AE5")
                .build();

        // Load the interstitial ad.
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        interstitial
                .setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        interstitial.show();
                    }
                });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ERROR  INSTERTITIAL");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I added Google analytics too and I can't see the nothing in the analytics dashboard

Comment: VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es 12-29  That's your problem right there.  You need to specify that your interstitial not be video.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I changed that in the ads from admob and nothing continuous the error

Comment: It doesn't make sense that it would be serving ads you told it not to.  There must be something else.  You may have your libraries for admob messed up.

Comment: Man I'll pay you for you help, I have three day with this error and I try everything and  admob and analytics don't work  @durbnpoisn

Comment: Let's try to work it out here...  Have you tried running the app without that Test Ad in there?  That could be the whole problem.